# AVPlayerViewController not displaying captions control

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, webvtt

I have an app that plays Vimeo videos in `AVPlayer`. Previously I played them in `AVPlayerLayer` and handled switching caption language (or hiding captions) with UI I implemented. Now I've been asked to switch to `AVPlayerViewController`, but when it plays the same videos its caption language switching UI (basically a little text bubble icon for the languages menu) never appears, and the video always plays with English captions, regardless of language selected in iOS Settings:General.

To create the `AVAsset` for `AVPlayer`, I fetch the captions as .vtt files, and create a combined `AVMutableComposition` with both the video, audio and text tracks using the following code. The videos can be cached locally or streamed so the URL path can be to a remote server or local, but I always download the text tracks so the `textTrackPath` is always local.

```swift
func createCaptionedVideoFrom(_ localVideoAsset: AVAsset, url: URL) -> AVMutableComposition? {
    do {
        let fileName = url.lastPathComponent
        
        guard let tracksRecord = TextTracks.tracksForGroupLesson(self) else {
            return nil // no langauge tracks
        }
        
        // Create resource for combined tracks
        let videoPlusSubtitles = AVMutableComposition()
        
        // Add video track
        guard let existingVideo = localVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[safe: 0] else {
            Logger.error("No video track in local video asset named: \(name) fileName: \(fileName)")
            return nil
        }
        guard let videoTrack = videoPlusSubtitles.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
            Logger.error("Could not create video track in new video named: \(name) fileName: \(fileName)")
            return nil
        }
        try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: localVideoAsset.duration), of: existingVideo, at: CMTime.zero)
        
        // Add audio track
        guard let existingAudio = localVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[safe: 0] else {
            Logger.error("No audio track in local video asset named: \(name) fileName: \(fileName)")
            return nil
        }
        guard let audioTrack = videoPlusSubtitles.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
            Logger.error("Can't create audio track in new video named: \(name) fileName: \(fileName)")
            return nil
        }
        try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: localVideoAsset.duration), of: existingAudio, at: CMTime.zero)
        
        for textTrack in tracksRecord.tracks {
            // add text track
            guard let textTrackPath = textTrack.cachedLocalPath else {
                Logger.error("Text track: \(textTrack) for group lesson: \(id) not cached for offline use.")
                return nil
            }
            let subtitleAsset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: textTrackPath))
            guard let existingTrack = subtitleAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .text).first else {
                Logger.error("No text track in local video asset named: \(name) fileName: \(fileName)")
                return nil
            }
            
            guard let subtitleTrack = videoPlusSubtitles.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .text, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
                Logger.error("Could not create text track in new video named: \(name) fileName: \(fileName)")
                return nil
            }
            
            subtitleTrack.languageCode = textTrack.language
            subtitleTrack.extendedLanguageTag = textTrack.language
            try subtitleTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: localVideoAsset.duration), of: existingTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
            
            if subtitleTrack.hasMediaCharacteristic(AVMediaCharacteristic.legible) {
                print("New \(textTrack.language) is legible")
            }
        }
        return videoPlusSubtitles
    } catch {
        Logger.error("Could not write text track for video lesson: \(name), error: \(error)")
    }
    return nil
}

func playVideo(_ video: AVAsset) {
    let assetKeys = [
        "playable"
    ]
    
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: video,
                                  automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: assetKeys)
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    videoPlayer.allowsExternalPlayback = true
    
    let avPVC = AVPlayerViewController()
    avPVC.player = videoPlayer
    avPVC.showsPlaybackControls = true
    self.present(avPVC, animated: true) {
        self.playerController = avPVC
        videoPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

The video, audio and text tracks are always created properly, and the text tracks always have the `mediaCharacteristic` of `legible`, and videos always have Spanish and English tracks. But weirdly the completed `AVMutableComposition` has no `mediaCharacteristics`.

a) `videoPlusSubtitles.availableMediaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions` always returns nil,

b) `videoPlusSubtitles.hasMediaCharacteristic(.legible)` always returns nil.

So why does `AVPlayerViewController` not display caption controls for both the English and Spanish tracks if it can see the English captions track?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm facing something similar. At first I thought that the captions menu was no longer working when selected. Then I noticed that sometimes when I long pressed the captions icon (a couple of seconds), the menu appeared.